# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_runtime()

Tags: magic-quotes

On my website, I have a Coppermine photoalbum integrated. It worked fine, but I think the error occured after php 8.0 was activated.

Heres the link to the photogallery of the site:
https://www.toneelgroepcontactharlingen.nl/cpg16x/

Heres the error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_runtime() in /customers/2/9/4/toneelgroepcontactharlingen.nl/httpd.www/cpg16x/include/init.inc.php:62 Stack trace: #0 /customers/2/9/4/toneelgroepcontactharlingen.nl/httpd.www/cpg16x/index.php(25): require() #1 {main} thrown in /customers/2/9/4/toneelgroepcontactharlingen.nl/httpd.www/cpg16x/include/init.inc.php on line 62

Can anybody help me to fix this?

Greetings, David

I tried to deactivate the get magic qoutes on line 62, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because it try to check if magic_quotes_runtime ios disabled, but if you have a recent version of PHP, this getter don't exist anymore. I recommande you to just comment the line of this test.